# Downloading a binary file using c++ and Qt

Tags: php, c++, qt

I want to download a *.exe file from a php script and execute it.

After I download the file I can' execute it anymore. When I look inside the file there are a lot question marks in it.

PHP script:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_name));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file_name);
exit;
```

C++:

```
 QFile offline_ip_adress_calculator(QDir::currentPath() + "/offline_ip_adress_calculator.exe");

    //Check if the File exists and clear its content
    if(!offline_ip_adress_calculator.open(QFile::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate))
    {
        msgBox.critical(this, "I/O error", "Can't open offline_ip_adress_calculator.exe for update");
        return;
    }

    QDataStream text_stream(&offline_ip_adress_calculator);
    while(reply->size() > 0)
    {
        QByteArray replystring = reply->read(2048);
        text_stream << replystring;
    }

    offline_ip_adress_calculator.close();
```

reply is a "QNetworkReply"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you treat binary data as text.

When you use `QDataStream::operator<<` the data from `replystring` is handled like a string. But it's no textual string, just a series of bytes.

Instead use [`QNetworkReply::read`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#read) and [`QFile::write`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#write):

```
char buffer[2048];
qint64 size = reply->read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
offline_ip_adress_calculator.write(buffer, size);
```

Comment: how did you chose buffer as 2048 ? if the file is greater than 2018 byte what happens ?

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan 2048 is a nice number in computer terms (a multiple of 2). And if there are more data to read it will simply take two (or more) iterations to read/write all.

Comment: You are wrong man.In my desktop App,I was trying to download a PNG.Only the upper half of the file is saved and the file size is being exactly 2.00Kb(2048 Bytes) on Windows. I am editing your answer for a clearer solution.

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan Then you clearly are not reading in a loop, or doing something other mistake. Instead of editing my answer (which answers the question asked) please post your *own* question. You should link to this question for clarity. And if you have a solution, then you can add your own answer immediately.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what is the advantage of using loop ? Is it doing something better than reply->readAll()?

Answer (score 2):

Here is  more clear and pure Qt Solution:

```
   QByteArray downloadedData = reply->readAll();
   QFile file("somefile");
   file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
   file.write(downloadedData.data(),downloadedData.size());
   file.close();
```

I have tried  @SomeProgrammerDude's solution.I downloaded a png file that way,got only upper half of the image and Not Surprisingly the file size was exactly 2048 or whatever number I set.